# Set up RAMMFAR for certain paths only

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 MVC app. I don't want to set RAMMFAR (`runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`) because that would needlessly send requests for static resources through the ASP.NET pipeline; however I do want all requests which begin with the path `/Download/` to run through the ASP.NET routing pipeline, regardless of extension. This way I can route them to a Controller and serve dynamically generated resources.

How can this be done? I do not have access to IIS settings but hopefully there is a way to do this through `web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

The RAMMFAR setting is per application. You'd have to create a separate IIS applications if you want different parts of the site to have different settings, but unfortunately you state this is not an option for you.

I two have two side notes though:

1. Are you sure you even need RAMMFAR? I think that when using IIS 7.5 and newer it's very rarely needed because IIS and ASP.NET can pretty much handle managed/native requests correctly.
2. Have you identified this as an actual problem to always have it enabled? Undoubtedly RAMMFAR will make things slower, but the question is whether it's causing a measurable effect in your app. Even if a static file does go through some managed code, the final processing of the file is handled back in native code. So there's a bit of extra work to go "through" the ASP.NET managed pipeline, but once that's done it's back to native IIS/Windows code.

Answer (score 0):

It is surprising to see that this hasn't been answered in Stack Overflow for long time.

As you've mentioned - runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is not required when you just need to capture all requests for a particular path in your site.

You can specify a path pattern which should be send to MVC handlers as shown below

```
<add name="DynamicDownloadHandler" path="/download/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Above pattern will capture both extensionless and paths with extension.

[A sample implementation for serving dynamic images in MVC is linked here](https://davidsekar.com/asp-net/dynamically-serving-images-with-extension-from-database).